# C# - upcasting to the the passed type of a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm using `ADO.NET EF` and `Repository pattern`. I want to separate some logic that is common for some of my entities and I decided that the best way is using generic method. This is the declaration of my method:

```
internal static void ChangeCode<T>(IService<T> service, Entity entity, MaskedTextBox txtBox, string newCode, long? entityId)
            where T : Common.DbContextEntities.Entity
```

`IService<T>` is the base class from which all services derive and `Entity` is the base class form which all entities derive. However in run time I  pass more specific service and entity like `SoleService` and `Sole`. What I would like to accomplish is somehow declare a `service` and `entity` to the run time type and those properties to be visible in from the whole method. To make it clear here is what I do now :

```
if (entity.GetType() == typeof(Sole))
            {
                Sole tempEntity = new Sole();
                ISoleService tempService = UnityDependencyResolver.Instance.GetService<ISoleService>();
```

The problem is that I can use `tempEntity` and `tempService` only in the scope of `if (entity.GetType() == typeof(Sole))` and if I have to check against several types (which is the case in fact) I have to repeat all the business logic for each different type. I am looking for a way to set `tempEntity` and `tempService` at run time with specific in a way that they could be used everywhere in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sole tempEntity = new Sole();
ISoleService tempService = UnityDependencyResolver.Instance.GetService<ISoleService>();
```

can be rewriten with

```
BaseService tempEnitity = (BaseService)Activator.CreateInstance(entity.GetType());
IBaseService tempService = tempEnitity.GetServiceInterface();
```

where BaseService is a parent for all services (SoleService etc), containig virtual method returning IBaseService, the parent of all service interfaces (ISoleService etc).

so, all your logic will work with methods of BaseService and IBaseService.

Comment: Hmm, `IService<T>` is this parent that you are writing about. But I think that creating of another Interface for the services that I want to call in my method is actually very good idea. Thanks. Gonna try it right now!